# Cannot create tag using Subclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, subclipse

I am using Subclipse, though my working copy is up to date I get the following error when creating a tag:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be confused about the error message. the `file` part in `file:///` does not mean that `test` is a file. It's an indication that the repository is located on the local storage support (file system).
However I have to admit That the error message isn't enough explicit in the part `already exists`. The solution to this issue is to create the tag into a non already existing folder.

In other words you should not create the folder that will hold your tag before this step (using `New Remote Folder` in view `SVN Repositories`). The folder should be created at the moment of the tag creation. This is done by adding the new folder (e.g `tag-folder`) to the URL i.e `file:///C:/Users/tunnaruto/Dropbox/Studies/pfe/repository/fo/test/tag-folder` and don't forget to check `Create any intermediate folders that are missing`.